# Ботинки-кошки / ботинки кошки / ботинки «кошки»

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Ботинки-кошки / ботинки кошки / ботинки «кошки».`

`Я забыл кошки/«кошки» свои надеть и упал.`

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ. Это вам только для дополнительной помощи, чтоб знали больше. Галочку, или принятие ответа, я от вас НЕ требую. Рекомендую оставить на том же месте, где она стоит сейчас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

(1) ***Ботинки-кошки.***

Приложение в постпозиции, дефисное написание. Вероятно, обувь **с шипами** на подошве.

(2) *Я забыл **«кошки»** свои надеть и упал.* Также (разг. речь): Я забыл ***кошки*** свои надеть и упал.

Нераспространенное слово, спортивный термин, поэтому **кавычки**.

Здесь кошки — это скорее гибкие **резиновые протекторы** с шипами, которые можно надеть на любую обувь.

[Модели кошек](https://www.kant.ru/articles/3276639/)

Comment: Кошки - это не обувь с шипами, а шипы отдельно и обувь отдельно, шипы называются "кошки". Кошки - это ледоступы, по вашей же ссылке, их на ботинки одевают, чтобы не скользить. Зачем плодить единорогов?

Comment: Чтобы было больше единорогов, они полезные)  // Ботинки отдельно, а протекторы отдельно. Вышел и забыл протекторы надеть.  У меня ссылка на них,  а вам еще на ботинки с шипами надо? Вот такие подойдут Дорого, правда) https://albione.ru/catalog/shoes/chernye-botinki-s-shipami-140fw/?utm_source=yandex&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=tk_general_msk&utm_term=---autotargeting&yclid=9338300710182715391

Comment: Это вообще не то) вы не различаете что ли? Железо от резиновой подошвы не отличаете? Бывает еще трекинговая обувь, там протектор, тоже называется шипы, но там резина. А бывают еще бутсы, там тоже шипы и бывают железные винтики, но это не кошки, никто не называет бутсы кошками или ботинками-кошками) Единороги полезны чем, кроме смеха?

Comment: Вам не угодишь, ищите сами ботинки-кошки.   И чтобы именно так назывался товар, а не ботинки с железными винтиками.

Comment: Так-с, ну ваш ответ можно плюсонуть. Впрочем, я это уже давно сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Все варианты верны, но разный смысл:

*Ботинки-кошки* — 'ботинки в виде кошек',

*Ботинки кошки* — 'ботинки, принадлежащие кошке',

*Ботинки «кошки»* — «кошки» — название ботинок.

Второй ваш пример рассмотрим.

Если вы имеете в виду 'ботинки в виде кошек' и, следовательно, пишите *ботинки-кошки*, то используем висячий дефис:

*Я забыл -кошки свои надеть и упал*.

Если «кошки» — название ботинок, то кавычки и остаются:

*Я забыл «кошки» свои надеть и упал*.

**Дополнено**

*Кошки* (без кавычек) тоже, по сути, является названием ботинок и без слова *ботинки* Так что без висячего дефиса тоже корректно:

*Я забыл кошки свои надеть и упал*.

Но если автор хочет подчеркнуть зависимость приложения от определяемого слова, то висячий дефис можно ставить:

*Я забыл -кошки свои надеть и упал*.

Answer (score 1):

Ушаков. КОШКА(но тут немного неверно, так как Ушаков видимо не разобрался и обозвал кошки обувью):

> 4. Небольшой якорь с тремя и более лапами. Рыбаки забросили кошку.
> 5. Обувь с острыми шипами для лазания на столбы. || То же, для хождения по ледникам.
> 6. В различного рода производствах — название особого вида крюков или скребков (тех.). || Род вилки — инструмент для вытаскивания за шляпку
>    гвоздей (тех.).

"Карта слов", КОШКИ(тут верно):

> 4. обычно мн. ч. (ко́шки, -шек). **Спец. Приспособления разных типов в виде металлических зубьев, прикрепляемые к обуви для лазанья на
>    столбы, по отвесным местам и т. д.** Катя глянула на верхушку
>    телеграфного столба, где с монтерскими кошками на ногах висел Сашка.
>    Б. Бедный, Девчата.
> 5. мн. ч. (ко́шки, -шек). Ременная плеть с несколькими концами, употреблявшаяся в старину для телесных наказаний. — Которого ленивым
>    сочтут, дерут без жалости розгами, батожьем и кошками. Никулин, России
>    верные сыны.

Так что ввиду ряда нюансов не стоит писать велосипед, а стоит писать просто:  кошки. Ботинки нужны для ходьбы - это обувь, а кошки нужны, чтобы карабкаться или цепляться.

**Я надел на ботинки кошки и вскарабкался на столб. / Собираясь в горный поход, я прихватил и кошки, чтобы залезть на гору.**

Ботинки-кошки - такого не бывает, потому что кошки, это приспособа в виде железных шипов, которая не обувь, а почти тоже что и ледоступы. Ботинки - это ботинки, шипы это шипы, их вместе не делают, потому что это никому не нужно. Шипы можно на любые ботинки одеть. **Кошки - это шипы, то что цепляется, а не ботики, или якорь, или крюк.**

Так что ботинки-кошки - речевая ошибка таки.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150005/discussion-on-answer-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.